# why need a dummy trajectory in joint_trajectory_action_controller.cpp

Tags: microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

in joint_trajectory_action_controller.cpp (robot_mechanism_controllers package)

```
// Creates a dummy trajectory
boost::shared_ptr<SpecifiedTrajectory> traj_ptr(new SpecifiedTrajectory(1));
SpecifiedTrajectory &traj = *traj_ptr;
traj[0].start_time = robot_->getTime().toSec();
traj[0].duration = 0.0;
traj[0].splines.resize(joints_.size());
for (size_t j = 0; j < joints_.size(); ++j)
  traj[0].splines[j].coef[0] = 0.0;
current_trajectory_box_.set(traj_ptr);
```

Why need to create a dummy trajectory?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64229/why-need-a-dummy-trajectory-in-joint_trajectory_action_controller.cpp/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a **hold position** trajectory: A single-waypoint at the current time set to maintain the current joint positions.

When the **JointTrajectoryActionController** starts, it defaults to holding the current position while it awaits for the first command to arrive.

Note: The code snippet you reference is from the init() method. Something similar also happens in starting(), so it seems that the snippet in init() is unnecessary and IMO could be removed.

Since you are asking many questions about this controller, are you planning on reimplementing it for a custom non-PR2 robot, or are you simply studying its internals?. FYI, a robot-agnostic implementation of this controller should land in the [ros_control](https://github.com/willowgarage/ros_control) project sometime in the next 3 months.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-04**:
Right now, I am just studying its internals. I might write other package to interface with it later.